# How to add a cipher on sftp:// nautilus UI debian OR How to require cipher for one specific user in SSH?

Tags: ssh, sftp, nautilus

i recently have in a server 2 users:

1. admingti
2. interfazpic

The user interfazpic connects through an SFTP client which requires that it have an encryption, because if I do not place a default encryption it cannot connect.

Well in this case I entered the /etc/ssh/sshd_config file and added the following line:

```
Ciphers aes128-cbc, aes192-cbc, aes256-cbc, blowfish-cbc, arcfour
```

And with that configuration, the user interfazpic enters without any problem, but the user admingti is a user who uses my department and adding those encryption when trying to use the command sftp:// in the nautilus it should not connect and when trying to enter through SSH this one requires encryption (ssh -c aes256-cbc admingti@10.2.xx.xxx)

So I can only think of these questions to solve the problem:

Is it possible to only ask the user interfazpic for encryption and how would the process be?

OR

Is it possible to add a default encryption to the SFTP connection in nautilus debian?

I hope you can help me with this problem.
Greetings.